# Best approach to recreate following insets

Tags: subdivision-surface, shrinkwrap, boolean-modifier

I have been unable to find a good method to recreate this pen cap. The solution that comes to mind is using a plane with sub-division and using shrink wrap to project it onto the dome>solidify>bool. This is clearly a bad way to do this if there is a better way please share it. Thanks in advance

Here is the image of the object
[image: pen cap]

Current result

[image: current]

Comment: Hello, we can't see any image

Comment: sorry, now its visible

Answer (score 5):

You could begin with a plane and draw the same shape:

[image]

Then give it an *Array* modifier (with a *Count* of 4) and a *Simple Deform* (*Bend* mode, 360°):

[image]

Move the horizontal edges in order to reduce the top:

[image]

Inset the shape and move it inwards:

[image]

Comment: Très élégant ..:)

Comment: Merci  ;)  et bravo pour l'usage des accents !

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to recreate it. This make a lot of sense, didn't knew about simple deform. Thanks Again